# Log Messages in Wolverine Indicating Possible Problem about Failed Route Determination

Tags: mediator, wolverine

I'm very new to Wolverine and noticed a bunch of INF level log messages when processing a request:

> [17:41:55 INF] No routes can be determined for Envelope #018d971d-986c-486f-9d65-5eaa449fa40b (String)
> [17:41:55 INF] No routes can be determined for Envelope #018d971d-986c-4abe-a382-bdd6417fe1f5 (String)
> [17:41:55 INF] No routes can be determined for Envelope #018d971d-986d-45f7-8202-d1dabd7ecaa2 (String)
> [17:41:55 INF] No routes can be determined for Envelope #018d971d-986d-4055-8ba5-e3981ef2d9fb (String)
> [17:41:55 INF] No routes can be determined for Envelope #018d971d-986e-4682-aacd-650b1ac4a466 (String)
> [17:41:55 INF] No routes can be determined for Envelope #018d971d-986e-406d-8891-4c8843cd92bb (String)
> [17:41:55 INF] No routes can be determined for Envelope #018d971d-986f-4fc1-b60d-8111b196fa5c (String)

The request still worked, matching the Query with the Handler and 200 OK response.

The handler retuned a simple list of strings `Task<IReadOnlyList<string>>`

Simple question, are these messages anything to worry about. (They're not exactly positive)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have come up with a way of making those log messages going away and perhaps learnt a bit about how you are meant to work with this library.

As you can see, my Handler returned a primitive type wrapped in a Task i.e. `IReadOnlyList<string>`.

When I wrapped that list in a response object, the log messages went away. I believe the concept of the Envelope requires a complex type to be returned from the handler. A notion of strong typing coming into play.

```
public class GetTimeZonesQueryResponse
{
    public IReadOnlyList<string> TimeZones { get; set; }
}
```

Hope this helps other newcomers to this framework.